# SQL Server equivelent to Arcmap Intersect for polygons?

Tags: polygon, sql, sql-server, intersection

I have three different sets of GEOMETRY Polygon datasets in SQL Server that completely overlap. I need to create a new dataset that has a polygon for each unique area of the three layers. So ultimately I need lots of puzzle pieces.

AND I need to accomplish it in SQL Server, not something like ArcMap.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895270.aspx#rel) help docs seem promising.  Here is an example from the help on to test for intersection:

```
DECLARE @geom1 geometry;
DECLARE @geom2 geometry;
DECLARE @result geometry;

SELECT @geom1 = GeomCol1 FROM SpatialTable WHERE id = 1;
SELECT @geom2 = GeomCol1 FROM SpatialTable WHERE id = 2;
SELECT @result = @geom1.STIntersection(@geom2);
SELECT @result.STAsText();
```

Looks like you can do all kinds of geometry operations

Comment: This only returns an intersection for two(2) distinct polygons. I need ALL intersections from ALL polygons in all three layers.